# Is there a way to programmatically refry a pdf?

Tags: .net, pdf

I am using itextsharp to open a dynamic xfa form, fill in the fields and save.
However the pdf is too big, and itext cannot flatten fields in dynamic xfa.
To work around the size, I want to programmatically refry the pdf.
i.e. I can manually open it open in acrobat reader and print it to pdf again and the size will go down from 5mb to 200k.
Is there anyway to do this programmatically on a server?

Answer (score 0):

Argh, this one is a pain.

I've had some success with PDF to PCL conversion and back again, but it still has issues and not very elegant.

I have since switched what Im doing to DOCX OpenXML, and then using Word Automation to export to PDF. 
Word automation appears to be very stable now compared to the last time I used it.
However Im using the conversion as a WCF service on a separate load balanced server just in case, and might write up a windows service to make sure those Word processes are quitting properly.